# nextjs how to add optional parameters using useRouter from next/navigation

Tags: reactjs, next.js, router

I'm building app with nextjs and app router. How to pass query parameters to useRouter from next/navigation? I know that next/router has this option.
I want to navigate to `http://localhost:3000/posts/pages/1?search=test` and pass optional parameter "test". Do I need to generate parameters part manually?